# Remove all timers from weblogic server

Tags: java, timer, ejb, weblogic

I've created several timers in my weblogic server but they were throwing errors. That problem is fixed but some timers are still alive in my weblogic. How can I delete them?

```
for (Object obj : timerService.getTimers()) {
            Timer t = (Timer) obj;
            t.cancel();
}
```

doesn't work because the timerService.getTimers() will get the timers from the class where the timer was created in but I don't have (and know..) that class anymore.

Comment: If you create your timers in a static method and keep a static reference to the timers, that should still be available to any classes loaded by the same class loader.

Comment: The timers aren't created by a static method.

Comment: but they could be if you want to keep track of all of them.

Comment: But they aren't, so how can I track and delete thoes not created from a static method?

Comment: If you have access to any of the code for the Timer class or the Timer service you can add a static registry as a static HashSet of Timers to the service or Timer class itself and use it to cancel any created timers. If you do not have this access why are you concerned about canceling the timers?

Comment: Because they otherwise would run indefinitely on my server? Access can't be gained.

Comment: If you kill the java process then the timers will stop too.

Comment: EJB timers are persistant by default.

Comment: I did not realize that you were talking about EJB timers.  You should be able to lookup the TimerService using the Initial Context to get a SessionContext, which keeps a reference to the TimerService.  You could do this in the same SessionContext as the EJB call and add the timers created to your own static map of Timers to keep track of all the timers created.

Comment: I thought I mentioned in my post but now I see I didn't. Sorry for the confusion. I'll try that!

Comment: I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530275/how-to-get-all-ejb-timers seeing thoes comments it seems it just can't be done on a "normal and acceptable way". Thereby the class I've created the timer in is already deleted and I have no idea what I named it so I guess I'm not going to be able to get that timer anymore. 

Getting the timer from the session just gets the timers from the bean where you get the session from. My guess (and I say guess) is that the timerService uses the sessioncontext by itself.